# How to select an option in select by text using jQuery

Tags: jquery

How to set an option in select by text using jQuery? The following works

```
$("#selectID option:contains('optionText')").attr("selected", true);
```

Is there a simpler/shorter way?

Example

```
<select id="fruit">
    <option value="">--select--</option>
    <option value="1">apple</option>
    <option value="2">pineapple</option>
    <option value="3">orange</option>
<select>
<br>
<button>apple</button>
<button>orange</button>
<button>pineapple</button>

$(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        $("#fruit option:contains('" + $(this).text() + "')").attr("selected", true);
    })
})
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c2cb9/2/)

**EDIT**

The version posted above using Contains has a bug. Since the Contains would match partial strings also (e.g. apple would match pineapple), it can select incorrect options.

```
// Doesn't work in FF4, IE9 using jQuery 1.4.4
$('#fruit').val('apple'); // Doesn't work in FF4, IE9 using jQuery 1.4.4

// Doesn't work either in FF4, IE9 using jQuery 1.4.4
$('#fruit option[text="apple"]').attr("selected", true);

// This works
$("#fruit").children("option[text='apple']").attr("selected", true);
```

**EDIT** Feb 14th, 2012

```
// The above doesn't work in jQuery 1.7.1

// Using even more verbose version [Demo][2]

var buttonText = $(this).text();

$("#fruit option:contains('" + buttonText + "')")
    .filter(function(i){
        return $(this).text() === buttonText;
    })
    .attr("selected", true)
```

Comment: Why do you want something shorter? That looks fine!

Comment: Actually, ran into this when on a page several inputs (type=text) as well as selects are being selected and then being set using something like elems.val(someCond ? newValue : ""). It works fine for both inputs and selects as long as the newValue is value of the selects. In some cases the selects need to be selected using text. I was trying to see if there is a generic way so that the script doesn't have to add another if to determine if the elem is input or select.

Comment: The version posted has a bug and $('#fruit option[text="apple"]').attr("selected","selected"); doesn't work either. Updated the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// Work in FF4, IE9 using jQuery 1.4.4 but has a bug (see original post)
$("#selectID option:contains('optionText')").attr("selected", true);

// Doesn't work in FF4, IE9 using jQuery 1.4.4
$('#fruit').val('apple'); // Doesn't work in FF4, IE9 using jQuery 1.4.4

// Doesn't work either in FF4, IE9 using jQuery 1.4.4
$('#fruit option[text="apple"]').attr("selected", true);

// This works
$("#fruit").children("option[text='apple']").attr("selected", true);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c2cb9/12/)

**EDIT** Feb 14th, 2012

```
// The above doesn't work in jQuery 1.7.1

// Using even more verbose version [Demo][2]

var buttonText = $(this).text();

$("#fruit option:contains('" + buttonText + "')")
    .filter(function(i){
        return $(this).text() === buttonText;
    })
    .attr("selected", true)
```

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to do:

```
$('#fruit').val('apple');
```

Actually, in the NEWER versions of JQuery, this doesn't work, you're right. Only thing I can think of is this:

```
$('#fruit option[text="apple"]').attr("selected","selected");
```

Is that even better than yours? ;)

Comment: Tried a variation. Doesn't work in FF4 and IE9. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c2cb9/4/)

Comment: This will at actually not work, because the selected list does not contain the value of apple. see: http://jsfiddle.net/c2cb9/4/

Comment: While the verbosity is same, it should fix one bug. Using "Contains" select first matched value so if the options happen to have the words common e.g. pineapple, apple. However it is not working. [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c2cb9/11/)

Comment: Have to use $("#fruit").children("option[text='" + $(this).text() + "']").attr("selected", true); [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/c2cb9/12/)

Answer (score -1):

It can be achieved like so:

```
<select id="fruit">
<option value="">--select--</option>
<option value="1">apple</option>
<option value="2">orange</option>
<select>
<br>
<button data-id="1">apple</button>
<button data-id="2">orange</button>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
         $("#fruit").val($(this).data('id'));
    });
});
```

This is just one way it can be done. You can also set your option values to 'apple' and 'orange' then use the following js instead.

```
$(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
         $("#fruit").val($(this).text());
    });
});
```